# Elasticsearch : 2 Node Cluster- Best way to shutdown one of the node

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently using a 2 node elastic cluster on RHEL. Both nodes are data nodes and one eligible master nodes. Currently I have a script to find the process id of the elasticsearch process and killing it as a way of stopping the elasticsearch. Is there any other way of safely stopping one of the node while another one is running.

Elasticsearch version 6.2.1

Comment: How are you starting your nodes? using `bin/elasticsearch` or via a service?

Comment: using bin/elasticsearch

Comment: Are you starting it in the background using `&` ?

Comment: The way you're doing it is the way you're supposed to do it :-) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/stopping-elasticsearch.html

Comment: Yes - bin/elasticsearch & . Thanks then I will stick with the same one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to stop your Elasticsearch node depending on how you're starting it.

If you're using [service management functionality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/rpm.html#rpm-running-init), you can simply issue a stop command for the elasticsearch service.

Otherwise, if you're running it in your terminal using `bin/elasticsearch &`, you can simply store the PID in a temporary file that you can lookup when you want to stop the node down.

You start your node like this by storing the PID of the process in `/tmp/elasticsearch-pid`

```
./bin/elasticsearch -p /tmp/elasticsearch-pid -d
```

And then when you need to shut down the node, you can simply retrieve the PID from the temporary file and kill the process.

```
$ cat /tmp/elasticsearch-pid && echo
15516
$ kill -SIGTERM 15516
```